# How to persist database of postgresql image with docker-compose and mapped volumes

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I have this docker-compose which work on Mac and Linux but not on Windows :(.
Any idea how to fix this?

---

p.s. I already know the solution with an external volume which I don't prefer because I want to be able to backup the database files.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
postgres:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
     - "./dotcms/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    image: "postgres:9.6-alpine"
    environment: 
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
```

error message:

```
...
postgres_1  | syncing data to disk ... initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/mypg/base/1": Invalid argument
postgres_1  | initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/mypg/base/12403": Invalid argument
postgres_1  | initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/mypg/base/12404": Invalid argument
postgres_1  | initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/mypg/base": Invalid argument
...
```

ends up with exit code 1

Comment: Docker for Windows *protect* the  HD against directly write on it. He asks for confirmation, and password will be required. Is not a good idea to not create an volume, but...
Didn't windows asked you for a confirmation and superuser password? Sometimes password is asked on a back window.

Comment: Yes it did. I am having this issue only with this docker, but I had created even others. the folders are created and mapped, in windows explorer

Comment: Maybe if you include the docker file i'll try to reproduce the error.

Comment: As you can see is an official image from Postgres: postgres:9.6-alpine
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/master/9.6/alpine